# Error publishing Blazor Webassembly with AOT (.Net 8.0) - Error : Precompiling failed for "aot-instances.dll" with exit code 1. Can not open image

Tags: .net, publish, webassembly

Error publishing Blazor Webassembly with AOT (.Net 8.0) - Error :
Precompiling failed for ProjectTest\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\aot-instances.dll.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Can not open image ProjectTest\ProjectTest.csproj

It worked with .net 7.0.  It fails with .net 8.0.

I ran dotnet workload install wasm-tools, since I got that error first with .net 8.0.  Then removed the bin and obj files for the entire solution.

I updated packages from nuget.  I updated all the package references to 8.0.0 where applicable in my project file.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this line in the project file:

```
<RunAOTCompilation>true</RunAOTCompilation>
```

to

```
<RunAOTCompilation>false</RunAOTCompilation>
```

and had a successful publish.

Comment: I realized I could turn AOT off and it would publish, but I wanted to publish with AOT.

Comment: I have the same issue, I have dev building without AOT not problem, I need releases to be AOT.

Comment: @purello Have you got the resolution without turning off the AOT?
In my case it is working correctly on local environment but fails with ADO Pipeline.

Comment: Still getting the same error locally and to Azure.